# Django database not always available

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings, django-database

I have specified multiple databases in settings.py. One of the databases is a local Oracle database which is only available on my computer at work. So when I open my site on a computer which does not have access to this Oracle database, I see the error `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.`.

So my code works as it should when I'm on my work computer, but fails when I use my page online from another computer which does not have access to the local Oracle database.

I don't want to access the local database remotely. I just want to ignore the error when I don't have access to the local Oracle database.

Comment: http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/projects.html#projects-settings

Comment: This doesn't make sense. It's not the location of your browser that determines access to the database, but the server: it's the server that access Oracle. Something else is going on here.

Comment: Daniel Roseman: Maybe it's because I haven't installed the cx_Oracle module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `local.py` file in your settings module that is unique for the environment you're working on. Given a settings module, you can put the following in your `__init__.py`:

```
try:
    import .local
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Then on the machine where the Oracle database is available, set the right settings in the local settings file, but don't check it in to your version control system (e.g. put it in `.gitignore`).

Also watch for the order in your settings, after you import your local settings, you shouldn't override them if you want to keep the changes. You can move the import down in the file, or just add the settings to the existing dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` statements in your `settings.py`, since it's just a Python script. So you can add a function to detect whether you are at work, and then use that function to decide whether the at work-only database should be added to the `DATABASES` variable.

```
# in settings.py

def at_work():
    'Determines whether the project runs at work'

if at_work():
    DATABASES = {...}
else:
    DATABASES = {...}
```

Of course, if your models depend on the database that is only available at work, you will need to add a mock database to enable use of the models elsewhere, even if there is no data available.

Comment: Thanks! How can I determine if I'm at my work computer?

Comment: You can set an environment variable, read the hostname, create a specific file for it at a location of your choice, ... There are numerous possibilities. Anything system-dependent will do.

Comment: i feel like, usually this is achieved by creating multiple settings files, http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/projects.html#projects-settings